# set video duration with tag

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph, watch, built-in

I use the built-in OpenGraph action type "watch" in my app. when I post this action I send just the link to the object page. As described in documentation "By default, start_time will be set to the publish time of the Open Graph story about the activity, and expires_in will be set to the duration of the video-type object as specified in its Open Graph object markup"
So the Open Graph object markup tells me, that the duration should be marked as

```
[meta property="video:duration"          content="runtime in secs"]
```

I set this property to 6000, so in the head of the page I have the following:

```
[meta property="og:type" content="movie" /]
[meta property="og:title" content="blabla" /]
[meta property="og:description" content="blablablablabla" /]
[meta property="og:image"  content="<image url>" /]
[meta property="og:video" content="content url"]
[meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"]
[meta property="video:duration" content="6000"]
```

But when I post the action, It seems to be finished i.e. it's written 'watched' instead of 'is watching' on my timeline.
Does anybody know, which property should I set on the page to let Facebook to get the right movie duration?

sorry for my english and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, could you open a report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post the link in a comment of this tread for others to subscribe to it?

However, you can workaround the issue by specifying the "expires_in" property in the Action itself. See the doc for details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch

Comment: I've created a report, thank you. The link to it is [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278101788950758)